# Create dynamic json element with variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html, angular-ui-grid

I want to create the json element dynamically..something like this:

for exam. if

var branch_name = "abc-cde";

Instead of "abc-cde" below I want the variable branch_name, so that I can replace it with other elements. please note the hyphen in abc-cde.

```
itemsarray["abc-cde_workunit"] = dataResponse.branch_descriptor["abc-cde"].workunit_id;
```

The above code is in angularjs. Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does

```
itemsarray[branch_name + "_workunit"] = dataResponse.branch_descriptor[branch_name].workunit_id;
```

not do what you're after?

Comment: saved my day...actually night.. thanks a lot @Stuart :)

Comment: my pleasure - pleased to be of some help! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually simpler than you might think.

```
itemsarray["abc-cde_workunit"] = dataResponse.branch_descriptor[branch_name].workunit_id;
```

Comment: in left hand side variable, abc-cde also I need as variable. something like this itemsarray["<branch_name>_workunit"]

Comment: In that case just replace ```itemsarray["abc-cde_workunit"]``` with ```itemsarray[branch_name_workunit]``` and make sure you set ```branch_name_workunit``` variable to a property of ```itemsarray```.